# MySQL Update Error 1093

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

This works in a table where `doc_id` is the primary key:

```
select count(*)+1 from doctor where 
exp > (select exp from doctor where doc_id='001');

+------------+
| count(*)+1 |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
```

But when I'm using the same select query to set a field in the table, it reports the following error:

```
update doctor set rank=
(  select count(*)+1 from doctor where 
   exp > (select exp from doctor where doc_id='001')
) where doc_id='001';

ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'doctor' for update 
in FROM clause
```

I can't understand which target table reference it is talking of. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This restriction is documented in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html):

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

As a workaround, you can wrap the sub-query in another sub-query and avoid that error:

```
update doctor set rank=
(select rank from (  select count(*)+1 as rank from doctor where 
   exp > (select exp from doctor where doc_id='001')
) as sub_query) where doc_id='001';
```

Comment: although it makes me wonder, is that restriction supposed to protect you from something that the workaround reveals or is it a technical problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a table you're updating in a subquery in the from clause. Try a join, or a double subquery :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you're reading and writing from the same table. This could be a preventive way of blocking writing because your update could affect the data being read.

You might need to separate the subquery into using an intermediate virtual table.